# How to split out data from Tiddlywiki

Tags: tiddlywiki

I love TiddlyWiki, but due to the content being buried inside a massive HTML document, it is difficult to use it under source control, among other things.

Is there a way to get it to store the data in a external data file (e.g. a large JSON file)? Alternatively is there a way to get it to save each Tiddle as a separate file so at least merge conflicts are less likely?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to get it to save each Tiddle as a separate file so at least merge conflicts are less likely?

You can run TiddlyWiki under node.js. See http://tiddlywiki.com/#TiddlyWiki%20on%20Node.js. This will serve your wiki through a local web address and save each tiddler as an individual file. In addition, you always have the option to save your wiki in a single html file again by clicking the save/download button in your wiki.

> Is there a way to get it to store the data in a external data file
>   (e.g. a large JSON file)?

A possibility is to open "advanced search" and use a filter expression to select a certain set of tiddlers. Then you can export your selection as a bundle in json format. See http://tiddlywiki.com/#How%20to%20export%20tiddlers.